# Two listeners triggered at the same time, removeEventListener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium

Hey, I have a listener attached to a row (createTableViewRow) and the row has an icon which has another listener, why the row listener is triggered when I click over the icon? removeEventListener doesn't work. This is the code: http://pastie.org/1157225

Any help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is probably a bug in the code (at least on Android) there as well to watch out for.

https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32238/tickets/2171-android-tableviewrowleftimage-interfers-with-custom-row-clicks#ticket-2171-1